# Remove duplicated dots from file name

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

I have a dir with tons of files inside which have been named in malformed such as `file..txt` ,`file2..txt` ,etc...

So how to easily remove this second `.` from file names?

Any applicable method is appreciated including awk,sed,grep,etc...

Comment: can it be more than two dots in the file name ?

Comment: No, all files have exactly two dots only

Comment: `.\n.` isn't `..`

Comment: Not from me. :\

Answer (score 5):

Using `rename` (as per heemayl's suggestion I narrowed down the globbing only to filenames ending exactly with `..txt`):

```
rename -n 's/(.*)\./$1/' *..txt
```

This will match the filename until the last dot and replace the match with everything but the last dot.

If the result is the expected one, remove the `-n` option:

```
rename 's/(.*)\./$1/' *..txt
```

Comment: @Maythux Also I chose this because it happens to be a little shorter, but if for some reason you have to match until the first dot you can just add a `?`: `rename 's/(.*?)\./$1/' *`

Comment: no it may happen to have some dots in file name,

Comment: kos, Rather than using `*`, use `*..txt` to get the files as only `*` will cause problem when you have any file with only one `.` (i mean in general case)

Comment: Doesn't work with newlines in the filenames

Comment: @heemayl Thanks for the suggestion, I agree, updated

Comment: @A.B. I know, that was intended; anyway I'm adding another way to to this that includes filenames containing newlines also.

Comment: That may fail if there are a very large number of files matching `*..txt`, so that the glob expansion exceeds the maximum command length (which is often 261,144 characters). A solution like the one from @Maythux using `for ...; do ...; done` will be more bulletproof.

Comment: @A.B. Why does this not work when there are new lines in the file name?  It looks clean to me (on that issue—there may be other issues to deal with).

Comment: ok, it works, but we have an error message: `Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /usr/share/perl5/File/Rename.pm line 69.`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not that it breaks or something, it simply discards filenames containing newlines due to the `Unsuccessful stat on filename`

Comment: @A.B. Yes, it's Perl discarding the file because of the `Unsuccesful stat on filename`, it just won't try to rename it and the file will be discarded.

Comment: already upvoted my friend. ;)

Comment: Thanks @ A.B., however @JonathanLeffler according to [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643520/remove-duplicated-dots-from-file-name/643523?noredirect=1#comment921675_643523) and to [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643520/remove-duplicated-dots-from-file-name/643523?noredirect=1#comment921668_643520) it should be pretty bullet-proof for OP's scope.

Comment: @A.B.       Hmmm…how on earth did who manage to break the code so it fails on names containing newlines?  That's a reportable bug in the `rename` utility IMNSHO.  It required effort to break it.  A basic implementation of `rename` doesn't run into that issue.

Comment: @A.B. Better question is why do you have files which have names with newlines in them...

Comment: @Doorknob Why not? It's a valid filename.

Answer (score 4):

I have a working solution, still working for better one:

```
for f in *; do mv $f ${f%.txt}txt; done
```

Thank to [@heemayl](https://askubuntu.com/users/216503/heemayl) note:

> Rather than using *, use *..txt to get the files as only * will cause
>   problem when you have any file without . and with only one

So becomes:

```
for f in *..txt; do mv $f ${f%.txt}txt; done
```

Comment: Rather than using `*`, use `*..txt` to get the files as only `*` will cause problem when you have any file without `.` and with only one `.`

Comment: @heemayl Perfect note, thanks, I just put `*` assuming i know file names hierarchy, but you are totally alright in general

Comment: Same here, not with newlines in a filename

Answer (score 4):

Another `rename` variant:

```
rename 's/\Q.././' *..txt
```

using `\Q` avoids escaping the dots (See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Comment: And with newlines in a filename? ;)

Comment: @A.B. it works, you only get a warning about Unsuccessful stat

Answer (score 2):

You may try the reverse order. This works if the filename contains newline characters.

```
rename 's/\.([^.]+)$/$1/' *..txt
```

Comment: ya.. you may try `rename 's/\.([^.]+)$/$1/s' *..txt` also.

Answer (score 2):

The very simple way to do this just run the following command inside the directory which contains the filenames in the format u mentioned above

```
rename 's/\.+txt/\.txt/' *
```

Comment: not for 'foo..bar..txt'

Comment: @A.B.  edited is that fine

Comment: Yes, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Filenames can contains a newline character, therefore:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}txt"; done
```

---

*Example*

```
$ find -exec  printf "%s ---" {} \;
. ---./foo
..txt ---./foo..txt ---

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
    while read -d $'\0' f; do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}txt"; done

$ find -exec  printf "%s ---" {} \;
. ---./foo
.txt ---./foo.txt ---
```

Comment: @Maythux The `?` is a newline char.

Comment: No, `ls` shows a `?`, I have changed my example.

Comment: touch "hello?..?txt"

Comment: @Maythux no, `touch "hello<RETURN>..txt"`

Answer (score 1):

This works quite well if there's no single-dot files:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file%%.*}${file#*.}"; done
```

Comment: No awk version? (already upvoted my friend ;) )